# To Verify that an ascii string contains unique character using bit operations without using additional data structures

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I tried to solve this problem, but my program fails when input contains small and capital version of same alphabet in input String, for ex:- Test, Abca.

```
// Assuming Input to be an ASCII String i.e a total of 128 unique characters, which map to the numbers 0–127.

public class Q1_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long firstHalf = 0; // 0 - 63
        long secondHalf = 0; // 64 - 127
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            byte b = (byte) x.charAt(i);
            System.out.println((char) b + " - " + b);
            if(b < 63) { // search firstHalf
                System.out.println("First Half");
                long mask = 1 << b;
                if((firstHalf & mask) == 0) { // unique character is encountered
                    firstHalf |= mask;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("String contains Duplicate Character");
                    return;
                }
            } else if(b > 63 && b < 128) {
                System.out.println("Second Half");
                long mask = 1 << (b - 64);
                if((secondHalf & mask) == 0) {  // unique character is encountered
                    secondHalf |= mask;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("String contains Duplicate Character");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ASCII String contains only unique character");
    }
}
```

As you can clearly see in output that program stops when it encounters 't'.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the bit shifting:

```
(1 << (b - 64))
```

Is done with *int*, not long, so the shifting repeats after 32 bits.

Make it long shifting by using:

```
(1L << (b - 64))
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Nice

Comment: It just zeros out the mask for anything `b >=32` or `(b - 64) >= 32` no?

Comment: @MadPhysicist it masks the first 5 bits of the number, [as described in the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

Comment: Did not know that. TIL. Thanks :)